# #define and then printf not working

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

For an assignment i must define a variable N as 100, then recall that variable in a printf statement. the code looks like :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <time.h>
#define N 100

int main ( )
{
...
printf("Try to guess a number between 1 and N \n\n") ;
...
}
```

The `N` is just coming out as `N` rather than `100`.

Comment: take a step back, and imagine how hard it would be for you to have a program write any meaningful text to the screen if the pre-processor would actually expand macros within char constants...

Answer (score 4):

This is because everything between double quotes are considered as a character array, i.e. a string. So if you want to show `N` in the string, you shall use it as an "usual" variable:

```
printf("Try to guess a number between 1 and %d \n\n", N) ;
```

Answer (score 4):

`#define` won't expand in literal character string (block of character between `"`). You should write:

```
printf("Try to guess a number between 1 and %d \n\n", N)
```